# How to create a nomination pool using CLI or API?

Tags: substrate-node

I want to create a nomination pool on a substrate based chain, I am using polkadot api, this is what I have managed to write till now

```js
const { ApiPromise, WsProvider, Keyring } = require('@polkadot/api');

async function createNominationPool() {
  // Define the WebSocket provider (use a Polkadot node endpoint)
  const wsProvider = new WsProvider('wss://goldberg.avail.tools/ws');

  // Create the API instance
  const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });

  // Create a keyring instance
  const keyring = new Keyring({ type: 'sr25519' });

  // Add your account to the keyring (replace 'YOUR_SEED_PHRASE' with your seed phrase)
  const account = keyring.addFromUri('I cannot tell you this I said NO why you still reading');

  // Define the parameters for the nomination pool (adjust as needed)
  const initialBalance = 100000000000; // Set the initial balance (in smallest unit, e.g., Plancks for Polkadot)
  const rootAccount = account.address;  // Set the root account of the pool
  const nominatorAccount = account.address; // Set the nominator account of the pool

  // Create the nomination pool
  const tx = api.tx.nominationPools.create(initialBalance, rootAccount, nominatorAccount, account.address);

  // Sign and send the transaction
  const hash = await tx.signAndSend(account);

  // Log the transaction hash
  console.log(`Created nomination pool with transaction hash: ${hash.toString()}`);
}

createNominationPool().catch(console.error);
```

I tried running it, it gives a runtime WASM error, but doesnt tell me what is really wrong

```
instruction executed
WASM backtrace:
error while executing at wasm backtrace:
    0: 0x2c59af - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind
    1: 0x7775 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::h7a368385936888dc
    2: 0x2812fd - <unknown>!TaggedTransactionQueue_validate_transaction: RuntimeApi, Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed\nWASM backtrace:\nerror while executing at wasm backtrace:\n    0: 0x2c59af - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind\n    1: 0x7775 - <unknown>!core::pa…
RpcError: 1002: Verification Error: Runtime error: Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed
WASM backtrace:
error while executing at wasm backtrace:
    0: 0x2c59af - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind
    1: 0x7775 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::h7a368385936888dc
    2: 0x2812fd - <unknown>!TaggedTransactionQueue_validate_transaction: RuntimeApi, Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed\nWASM backtrace:\nerror while executing at wasm backtrace:\n    0: 0x2c59af - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind\n    1: 0x7775 - <unknown>!core::pa…
```

Any help to resolve this error or suggesting a new method to do this would be appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve and capture the error the extrinsic is getting. Check this example in the PolkadotJS documentation: [How do I get the decoded enum for an ExtrinsicFailed event?](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/cookbook/tx/#how-do-i-get-the-decoded-enum-for-an-extrinsicfailed-event)

```js
const hash = await tx.signAndSend(account, ({dispatchError }) => {
 if (dispatchError) {
      if (dispatchError.isModule) {
        // for module errors, we have the section indexed, lookup
        const decoded = api.registry.findMetaError(dispatchError.asModule);
        const { docs, name, section } = decoded;

        console.log(`${section}.${name}: ${docs.join(' ')}`);
      } else {
        // Other, CannotLookup, BadOrigin, no extra info
        console.log(dispatchError.toString());
      }
});
```